# (.*) instead of (.*?)

Tags: php, regex

Suppose we have this html content, and we are willing to get Content1, Content2,.. with regular expression.

```
<li>Content1</li>
<li>Content2</li>
<li>Content3</li>
<li>Content4</li>
```

If I use the line below

```
preg_match_all('/<li>(.*)<\/li>/', $text, $result);
```

i will get an array with a single row containing:

```
Content1</li>
<li>Content2</li>
<li>Content3</li>
<li>Content4
```

And by using this code:

```
preg_match_all('/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/', $text, $result);
```

i will get an array with 4 row containing Content1, Content2, ...

Why (.*) is not working since it means `match any character zero or more times`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`*` matches in a *greedy* fashion, `*?` matches in a *non-greedy* fashion.

What this means is that `.*` will match as *many* characters as possible, including all intermediate `</li><li>` pairs, stopping only at the last occurrence of `</li>`. On the other hand, `.*?` will match as *few* characters as possible, stopping at the first occurrence of `</li>`.

Answer (score 6):

Because `.*` itself is greedy and eats up as much as it can (i.e. up to the last `</li>`) while still allowing the pattern to match. `.*?` on the other hand is not greedy and eats up as little as possible (stopping at first `</li>`).